# AJAX Jquery in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to pass data from view to Controller, but data not passing
so what is wrong in my app ?

in view:

> var url = 'searchs/index';
>
> $( "#h" ).click(function() {
>
> ```
>    $.ajax({
>        type: "GET",
>        url: url,
>        data: {xx: 'q'}
>    });
> ```
>
> });

Controller:

> class SearchsController < ApplicationController
>
> def index
>
> @x=User.new(:name=> params[:xx])
>
> @x.save
>
> end
>
> end

Comment: specify path in url ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

var url = 'searchs/index';

With this

var url = '<%= searchs_path %>';

Answer (score 1):

You should first follow the convention of Rails RESTful routing and use the `index` endpoint as a way to list all "searchs." I don't get why you are doing `UsersController#create` stuff in `SearchsController#index`.

Anyway, once you straighten that out, let's say you have some controller endpoint called `SearchsController#custom` (you shouldn't call it that, but I cant think of anything better) that you map to `searchs_custom_path`.

Then do something like this in your template:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "searchsCustomPath", searchs_custom_path %>
```

Then in your JavaScript do this:

```
$( "#h" ).click(function() {    
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: $("#searchsCustomPath").val(),
       data: {xx: 'q'}
   });
});
```

This way you don't hardcode the URL and violate DRY while still making the right Rails-generated URL available to JQuery.

Comment: He could also add the URL as a data attribute on `#h`, and use something like `$(this).data('search-url');` (depending on jQuery version) to access it.